# Order topology on $\omega \cup \{ \omega \}$ is not metrizible

Tags: general-topology

This is an early exersize in Topology and Geometry by Bredon. I don't understand, what is wrong with the embedding $\{ -\frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \} \cup \{0 \}$ in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Are you sure it's not supposed to be $\omega_1\cup\{\omega_1\}$? $\omega\cup\{\omega\}$ is second-countable compact Hausdorff, so it's clearly metrisable.

Comment: the book actually uses $\Omega$. what do I take this to mean?

Comment: "$X = \Omega \cup \{\Omega\}$ is the set of ordinal numbers up to an including the least uncountable ordinal $\Omega$, under the order topology"

Comment: Ok! No countable basis at $\Omega$!

Comment: Indeed. Or the space is compact but not separable (which cannot happen for metrisable spaces).